# No Host tab after installation of DNN 7.02.00

Tags: configuration, dotnetnuke, local

I just installed DNN locally and the host tab does not exist. I already went into the database and changed the Host tab to IsVisable=true and it is still not showing on my superuser account. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're connected with a superuser account ?
The Host menu is not accessible to the administrators.

Moreover, I'm not sure that "Host" tab needs to be flaggued as visible.
Take care that changing value in database could require you refresh the website cache. You could do that with recycle of the corresponding application pool.

Regards
Stéphane

Comment: how would i recycle the application pool?

Comment: I suggest you 3 methods: use IIS Manager to recycle the pool OR stop the w3wp process with the task manager OR modify the web.config file with a blank line for example and save it.

Comment: Please verify that you're connected with a superuser account. Then, get the tabid of the "host" tab in the database and load the default URL (for example localhost/default.aspx) by adding "?tabid=XX" in which XX is the tabid you got in the database. It should load the "host" tab.